# CDK - Check multiple repos

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I was wondering how to have a stack that checks multiple pipelines. I would like it to check all the pipelines in my project and send an alert in case one of them fails.

PLUS: Would like to integrate a linting tool for all the pipelines. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CodeStarNotifications for that, see the examples in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codestarnotifications-readme.html)